# Why are stepper motors sometimes rated in AC voltage?

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

Now, I think I get why steppers are rated at (for example) 48VDC - as I beleive it's to overcome any back-EMF, and that's why stepper controllers are typically constant(/max) current devices - they'll use the available voltage to get the stepper moving, up to the rated current.

But where it gets confusing for me is when they begin rating it in volts AC... Or sometimes only offering an AC voltage rating... eg.. "9Nm 100VAC". I'm hoping someone can explain exactly what they mean when they specify that AC rating, as there is little point applying an AC voltage to a brushless DC motor.

(Example image below from a Leadshine Stepper datasheet showing performance transitions from expected DC voltages, to an AC voltage)

[image: Leadshine Stepper Performance Graph]
PS: "They just got it wrong because it's a cheap chinese brand" is an invalid answer, as this DC/AC rating ambiguity is present across a lot of brands - including very expensive German ones.

Comment: I don't know for sure why they rate them like that but I do know that on the 4-wire motors the current reverses on every third step. It alternates.

Comment: I wonder what happened to the Moderator who is the citation link enforcer

Answer (score -1):

It is the rating of the driver+motor, not of the motor alone. In the graph you have the same motor, powered with different supply voltages / different drivers. You have three versions 48VDC, 70VDC and 110VAC.